# Specific libaries of service ignored by axis2

Tags: service, jar, apache-axis

I have an axis2 service deployed as an aar-file which contains service specific libaries. I have problems with the httpclient-4.2.jar and httpcore-4.2.jar and the error messages seems to me like not the service jars are loaded but the axis2 jars (which contains httpcore-4.0.jar).

The structure from the aar-file is like the following which should be correct:

```
aar
|- lib
|--|- httpclient-4.2.jar
|--|- httpcore-4.2.jar
|--|- LICENSES
|- my
|--|- services
|--|--|- *.class
|- META-INF
|--| - services.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JARS in .aar are not 100% the same context like WEB-INF/lib but also not 100% separated.
That is the reason why we do not package libraries and logic into the .aar file.
We put only the service.xml in the aar file. Classes are inside WEB-INF/lib JARs. 
By doing so you have the regular webapp context and your service is also able to return all object types/classes that are in the WEB-INF/lib context.

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem in my case is that the JARs already exist in WEB-INF/lib but in an older version that is needed for my service. So i can't place the JARs in WEB-INF/lib as axis2 itself would not work anymore. What to do?

Comment: I think your only chance is to update to latest Axis2. We are currently using Axis2 1.7.0 snapshot with httpclient-4.2.jar, which is running fine. I think if you simply upgrade to 1.7-SNAPSHOT of Axis2 you could resolve your JAR dependency issues. I think Axis2 1.7 also contains many bug fixes that we relied on.

Comment: Ok i'll try the new Axis2 version. I hope we will never have a case where no updated Axis2 with the same JARs as our service needs exists ;-)